# Creating an xml parsing function in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing

I have an XML that's obtained from a web service, i'm using an HttpClient for it. This is what the XML looks like:

```
<respuesta>
  <entrada>
    <rut>7059099</rut>
    <dv>9</dv>
</entrada>
<status>
  <code>OK</code>
  <descrip>Persona tiene ficha, ok</descrip>
</status>
<ficha>
  <folio>3204525</folio>
  <ptje>7714</ptje>
  <fec_aplic>20080714</fec_aplic>
  <num_integ>2</num_integ>
  <comuna>08205</comuna>
  <parentesco>1</parentesco>
  <fec_puntaje>20070101</fec_puntaje>
  <personas>
    <persona>
      <run>7059099</run>
      <dv>9</dv>
      <nombres>JOSE SANTOS</nombres>
      <ape1>ONATE</ape1>
      <ape2>FERNANDEZ</ape2>
      <fec_nac>19521101</fec_nac>
      <sexo>M</sexo>
      <parentesco>1</parentesco>
    </persona>
    <persona>
      <run>8353907</run>
      <dv>0</dv>
      <nombres>JUANA DEL TRANSITO</nombres>
      <ape1>MEDINA</ape1>
      <ape2>ROA</ape2>
      <fec_nac>19560815</fec_nac>
      <sexo>F</sexo>
      <parentesco>2</parentesco>
    </persona>
  </personas>
</ficha>
```

I'm trying to make a function that can parse this and, right now (just for the purpose of testing my understanding of the language since i'm new to it) i just need it to find the VALUE inside an "rut" tag, the first one, or something like that. More precisely I need to find a value inside the XML and return it, so i can show it on a label that's on my .aspx page. The code of my parsing function looks like this:

```
public static String parseXml(String xmlStr, String tag)
    {
        String valor; 
        using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlStr)))
        {
            try
            {
                r.ReadToFollowing(tag);
                r.MoveToContent();
                valor = r.Value;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException); 
            }
        }
        return valor;
    }
```

This code is based on an example I found on youtube made by the guys from microsoft where they "explain" how to use the parser.

Also, this function is being called from inside one of the tasks of the HttpClient, this is it:

```
protected void rutBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {                                                       
        if (rutTB.Text != "")                               
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            String xmlString = "";
            String text = "";
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("*******:*******"); //WebService's server authentication
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://wschsol.mideplan.cl");
            var par = "mod_perl/xml/fps-by-rut?rut=" + rutTB.Text;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            client.GetAsync(par).ContinueWith(
                (requestTask) =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage resp = requestTask.Result;  
                        try
                        {
                            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            XmlDocument xmlResp = new XmlDocument();    
                            requestTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(
                            (streamTask) =>
                            {
                                xmlResp.Load(streamTask.Result);             
                                text = xmlResp.InnerXml.ToString();
                                xmlString = parseXml(text, "rut");  //HERE I'm calling the parsing function, and i'm passing the whole innerXml to it, and the string "rut", so it searches for this tag.     
                                Console.WriteLine("BP");
                            }).Wait();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
                        } 
                    }).Wait();
            testLBL.Text = xmlString;  //Finally THIS is the label i want to show the "rut" tag's value to be shown.
            testLBL.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            testLBL.Text = "You must enter an RUT number";
            testLBL.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when i put some breakpoints into the parsing function i can see that it's receiving correctly the innerxml string (as a string) but it's not finding the tag called "rut", or rather not finding anything at all, since it's returning an empty string ("").

I know that maybe this is not the correct way to parse an xmlDocument, so if someone can help me out i'd be really really thankful.

EDIT:
Ok, so i won't ask for any tutorial or such (I requested that to avoid asking noob questions). But anyway, please, instead of just answering "you better do it like this", I'd appreciate if you could explain me things like "THIS is what you're doing wrong and THAT'S why your code isn't working", and THEN tell me how you guys would do it instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: You should get rid of that `try/catch/throw new Exception`. The exception will propagate without your help, and you are messing up the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

As you only want to retrieve a single field value I would recommend using Xpath.
Basically you create a XpathNavigator from a XpathDocument or xmlDocument and then use Select to get the content of the rut node:

```
XPathNavigator navigator = xmlResp.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator rutNode = navigator.SelectSingleNode("/respuesta/entrada/rut");
string rut = rutNode.Value
```